# getting unhashable type: 'list' while using .split()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using python 3 to begin with. I am trying to split the input from the console to match a key in my dictionary and the display the value of said key on the console. I've been trying things for hours and have decided to break down and ask for help. Here's some of the code.

```
enter = input("test  ").split()
names1 = {8410:"A", 8422:"B", 8450:"C", 8386:"D", 8394:"E", 8395:"F", 8318:"G", 8451:"H", 8348:"I", 8294:"J", 8349:"K"}
if enter in names1:
    print(names1[enter])
```

I have 16 dictionaries with 7000+ names in them with employee ids. My main goal here is to be able to type in a URL that has an ID in it, ex: www.domain.com/8450 and have the console only grab the 8450 and then display C.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you know your URLs are going to be like that use `rsplit('/')` like so:

```
>>> enter = int(input('test: ').rsplit('/')[-1])
test: www.domain.com/8450
>>> enter
8450
>>> names1[enter]
'C'
```

Also your keys are stored as ints so convert the input to int using `int()`.

Answer (score 0):

`split()` returns a list

Eg:

```
>>> input('test:').split()
test:hello
>>>  ['hello']
```

You are checking if any of the keys in the dict are a list, like this:

```
>>> if ['input'] in {'input': 'sample data'}
```

Which will not work.

You need to sanitize your inputs. There's many ways to do this. One example might be:

```
>>> if isinstance(enter, list):
>>>     enter = enter[0]
```

The choice is yours.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by sanitizing? I don't understand how that code is suppose to pertain to mine.